No internet connection on Hyper-V virtual machine in VPS
I am running a Windows 10 virtual machine (Hyper-V) on Windows Server 2022 (VPS). I need my virtual machine to be on the same LAN as my Windows Server. To do this, I have configured a virtual switch as follows:

After that I specified this switch in the virtual machine settings:

However, there is still no internet connection in the virtual machine itself:

Please help me to solve this problem. If you need additional details for clarification - ask me and I will attach everything needed.

@John, No, it doesn't work either.
